# java.lang.StackOverflowError when initializing OkHttpClient

Tags: java, jetty, okhttp, jvm-arguments, jetty-9

I am trying to initialize Okhttpclient from my webapp which is running inside a Jetty container (jetty-distribution-9.4.32.v20200930). Everything runs fine if I am on OkHtp 3.X (3.14.9). After I upgraded to OkHttp 4.9.0 (OkHttp 4.X changes implementation language from Java to Kotlin), my aplication fails to start-up with the following error:

```
2020-10-29 01:28:44.163:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@6581dc0a{Spidey,/jettyspideytest-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT,file:///private/tmp/jetty-0_0_0_0-8080-jettyspideytest-1_0_0-SNAPSHOT_war-_jettyspideytest-1_0_0-SNAPSHOT-any-15131256877380373917.dir/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{/opt/jetty-distribution-9.4.32.v20200930/webapps/jettyspideytest-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war}
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:550)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.foundClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:650)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadAsResource(WebAppClassLoader.java:623)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:535)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:550)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.foundClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:650)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadAsResource(WebAppClassLoader.java:623)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:535)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:550)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.foundClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:650)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadAsResource(WebAppClassLoader.java:623)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:535)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:550)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.foundClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:650)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadAsResource(WebAppClassLoader.java:623)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:535)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:550)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.foundClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:650)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadAsResource(WebAppClassLoader.java:623)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:535)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:550)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.foundClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:650)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadAsResource(WebAppClassLoader.java:623)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:535)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:550)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.foundClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:650)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadAsResource(WebAppClassLoader.java:623)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:535)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:550)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.foundClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:650)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadAsResource(WebAppClassLoader.java:623)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:535)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:550)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.foundClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:650)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadAsResource(WebAppClassLoader.java:623)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:535)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:550)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.foundClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:650)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadAsResource(WebAppClassLoader.java:623)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:535)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:550)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.foundClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:650)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadAsResource(WebAppClassLoader.java:623)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:535)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:550)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.foundClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:650)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadAsResource(WebAppClassLoader.java:623)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:535)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:550)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.foundClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:650)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadAsResource(WebAppClassLoader.java:623)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:535)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at okhttp3.internal.Util.<clinit>(Util.kt:592)
    at okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner.<clinit>(TaskRunner.kt:309)
    at okhttp3.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.kt:41)
    at okhttp3.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.kt:47)
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder.<init>(OkHttpClient.kt:471)
    at com.sitescout.dsp.adstxt.servlets.AdsTxtServlet.init(AdsTxtServlet.java:25)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$Wrapper.init(ServletHolder.java:1313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:602)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:414)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.lambda$initialize$0(ServletHandler.java:772)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:357)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:796)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1457)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1422)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:911)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:441)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:784)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:753)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:641)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:605)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.lambda$main$2(XmlConfiguration.java:1908)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1857)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:491)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:77)
```

Observations

1. I only get this when I use Jetty. If I use Tomcat 8.5 I do not run
   into this stackoverflow.
2. This only happens when I call
   OkHttpClient.Builder(). If I dont use the builder and instantiate it
   using new OkHttpClient(), I dont run into the stackoverflow.
3. I am using Xss256k instead of default 1024k. Simply bumping up my
   stacksize to 278k seems to fix the issue. However, this is dependent
   on OS. In Debian 9, 278k is the lower threshhold. In my local
   machine running macOS mojave I can make do with 258k.

I beleive this happens because of the way jetty is loading the kotlin compiled classes and looking for them via recursive calls, the stack was getting bigger and eventually hitting the 256k limit. Although I have fixed it by bumping up the Xss, I find this behavior rather odd. Hence, I shall appreciate your comments.

Comment: This just plain looks like a reportable bug to jetty project.